Why Does My Jenkins Job Reset After Completion When Triggered by Gerrit?
I'm using a Jenkins pipeline that is triggered by Gerrit. After the job completes, it seems to reset, which causes issues with subsequent steps or tracking the results. Here is the relevant part of my pipeline configuration:
pipeline {
agent {
    label "builder"
}
environment {
    PROJ_ROOT = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
    BUILD_NUMBER = "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
triggers {
    gerrit(triggerOnEvents: [
        patchsetCreated()
    ])
}
stages {
    stage("Preparation") {
        steps {
            script {
                // clone project and checkout specific change
                sh """
                git clone https://ci-tw.xxx.com/gerrit/${env.GERRIT_PROJECT} ${env.uniqueProjectDir}
                cd ${env.uniqueProjectDir}
                git checkout ${env.GERRIT_BRANCH}
                git fetch origin ${env.GERRIT_REFSPEC}
                git checkout FETCH_HEAD
                """
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Run CIP Build and Tests") {
        steps {
            script {
                // run build and tests
                def buildResult = sh(script: "./bin/build/run_cip_build.sh", returnStatus: true)
                if (buildResult != 0) {
                    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                    error "Build or tests failed."
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Cleanup Docker") {
        steps {
            script {
                sh """
                docker ps -q --filter "status=exited" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm || true
                docker network prune -f || true
                docker images -q --filter "dangling=true" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi || true
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
post {
    always {
        echo "Pipeline finished."
        script {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
    failure {
        echo "Pipeline failed."
    }
    success {
        echo "Pipeline succeeded."
    }
}

}
The Issue:
Whenever my Jenkins job fails, the Gerrit trigger settings get reset.
Questions:

Has anyone encountered similar issues with Gerrit-triggered Jenkins jobs?
What could be causing this reset behavior?
I'm not sure if cleaning the workspace is causing the issue, but is there a safer way to perform the cleanup??


What does deleteDir() do?

As stated in the comment above, the deleteDir() (alike the cleanWs()) deletes the current workspace directory - in your post execution case it is the whole workspace.

The primary purpose of using deleteDir() is to ensure that the testing environment remains clean, which is why deleting the current project folder is necessary. Given this goal, using sh rm -rf might be more appropriate in this context as it provides more control over the deletion process. This command directly removes the specified directory and its contents, ensuring that no residual files or folders are left behind.

Are you asking why the workspace is empty after you have deleted it?

No, the main issue is that the Gerrit trigger settings are being reset each time.

After testing, I found that the problem seems to be related to the triggers set in the Pipeline. This causes the Gerrit trigger to be reset every time the job fails.
triggers {
gerrit(triggerOnEvents: [
    patchsetCreated()
])

}
